# Not being able to change the data type of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to change the data type of the values in the column "id" from integer to string and then save the new dataframe to a CSV file. This is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv ('DataSet.csv', header=[0], on_bad_lines='skip', sep = ';')
df["id"] = df["id"].astype(str)
```

When I run the code below, it shows me that the data type has been changed successfully:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(type(row['id']))
```

Therefore, the result will be

```
<class 'str'>
```

for all rows.
However, when I save the dataframe to a CSV file,

```
df.to_csv('NewData.csv', sep = ';')
```

, read it again and run the following code,

```
for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
        print(type(row['id']))
```

, the result is integer for all rows. So, it seems that nothing has been changed at all.
Does someone know how this can be solved?

Comment: because `pd.read_csv` converting strings to integers by default. If need avoid it use `pd.read_csv(file, dtype={'id':str})`

Comment: the CSV format does not save the types. It can be interpreted differently during reading the data. You should explicitly define the types when **reading** the data

Answer (score 2):

In `csv` file are all values saved like strings, pandas by default converting types like `int, float` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) metdod.

So is necessary always converting to strings, simplier like your solution is use `dtype` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('DataSet.csv', dtype={'id':str}, on_bad_lines='skip', sep = ';')
```

If need save values always with their types use [`DataFrame.to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) and [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html).